# Selenium InternetExplorer 11 - Succesive Alert - Text Empty on the second Alert

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

Hello (excuse my English),

I have the following problem using Selenium WebDriver with IE 11.
When I try catching alert text, I manage getting the first text on the first alert.
As soon as I accept the first alert, the second alert is displayed but the text is empty although I can accept it.
I really don't understand this problem.
Can you help me please ?

Here is my code :

```
    public class AlertDemo {

    static WebDriver driver;
    static Wait<WebDriver> wait;

    static String driverPath = 
      "C:\\Users\\Acer\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.1\\";

     public static void main(String[] args) throws 
 NoAlertPresentException, 
     InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("*******************");
        System.out.println("Lancement INTERNET EXPLORER pour 
  tester la popup");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", driverPath + 
  "IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // Alert Message handling

  driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/test/delete_customer.php");

        driver.findElement(By.name("cusid")).sendKeys("53920");
        driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).submit();

        // Switching to Alert
        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 
  2);

  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

            // Capturing alert message.    
            String alertMessage = 
     driver.switchTo().alert().getText();

            // Displaying alert message     
            System.out.println(alertMessage);

            // Accepting alert
            System.out.println("On accepte OK");
            alert.accept();

            Thread.sleep(500);
            //Pour le message en retour
            /*wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);

          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());*/



            Alert alert2 = driver.switchTo().alert();
            System.out.println("TEXTE " + 
                     alert2.getText());
            System.out.println("TEXTE2 " + 
                             alert.getText());
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            if (alert2 == null) {

                System.err.println("Pas de popup !!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("OK la popup pour le 
  retour n'est pas nulle");
                Thread.sleep(2000);

                if 
                (!"".equals(driver.switchTo().alert().getText())) {

                    System.out.println(" Le texte 
     de la popup suivante est  " + driver.switchTo().alert().getText());
                    alert2.accept();
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Erreur: on 
  arrive pas à retrouver le texte");
                    System.out.println("Je vais 
   cliquer OK");
                    alert2.accept();
                }
            }

        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Pas trouvé d'alert");

        }
    }


}
```

The aim of this is to get String text contained in the second alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you accept the first alert, second alert comes with the checkbox that says 
"**Don't let this page create more messages**". In Internet Explorer driver somehow it prevents it to be read. Other browsers such as Chrome, there is not any problem.

To solve this issue, you simple need to add the website into `trusted sites` in Internet Explorer options. Then, you can get the text of the second alert.

Comment: Glad to see that is working. Please accept as an answer.